# PHP, Eval code result in a variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using eval to execute php code that is coming from a database. The code is for meta tags and page title. One example looks like this (this is stored in a table):

```
$name . " test page title |".SiteSettings::getSiteNameAlternate();
```

And then in the controller I do this ($seo is an object that has the meta_title, and that element has the exact string from the db):

```
$pageTitle = isset($seo->meta_title) ? @eval("echo $seo->meta_title") : null;
```

I am using Larevel framework and I pass that page title to the blade template, and this works. The blade code

```
<title>{{ isset($page_title) ? $page_title : SiteSettings::defaultPageTitle() }}</title>
```

The issue is because the echo in the eval I get the page title on top of the page also.

I tried using print (dumb I know) and printf. Did not work. Any idea how to put the value of that eval in a variable without output on the screen?

Comment: You are using `eval` for waht? Are you sure you didn't take a wrong turn somewhere?

Comment: I probably did take a wrong turn, but I don't see any other way of executing php code from the db

Comment: Executing code from a DB is generally a bad idea. Executing code from eval is generally a bad idea. There are occasional justifiable reasons for doing it, but they're rare. Usually when people write code like this, they're trying to create a flexible CMS type platform that allows the end user to add code to the system without needing the developer to make changes. This is based on a fallacy because who's going to write that code if not a developer? If you do need a configurable system, the correct way would be via a system of installable plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pageTitle = isset($seo->meta_title) ? @eval("return $seo->meta_title;") : null;
```

it will assign `$seo->meta_title` to `$pageTitle` if `$seo->meta_title` is set, and `null` otherwise.

Comment: Correct, but then my page title looks like this:
<title>$name . " test page title | ".SiteSettings::getSiteNameAlternate();</title>

Answer (score 2):

A good way to store results is with ob_start, ob_get_contents and ob_end_clean

```
/*start buffering;*/
ob_start();

eval(echo isset($seo->meta_title) ? $seo->meta_title : "");

/* now catch the Buffer of the eval */

$pageTitle = ob_get_contents();

/* pageTitle contains now the value of the buffered echo */

/* stop buffering; */

ob_end_clean();
```

now use the Controller as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand your question correctly, the issue appears because you did an `echo` inside `eval` which will then executed. So instead, you should store the value of `$seo->meta_title` to variable and then let the view `echo` it.

In your controller, store meta title value as page title if `isset`, unless `null`

```
$pageTitle = null;
if (isset($seo->meta_title)) {
    $metaTitle = '';
    eval("\$metaTitle = \"$seo->meta_title\";");
    $pageTitle = $metaTitle;
}
```

Then in your view

```
<title>{{ isset($page_title) ? $page_title : SiteSettings::defaultPageTitle() }}</title>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works, but @Jocelyn answer is cleaner. Also your are missing a ")" in the if statement